# Как число со знаком "e-" конвертировать в строку?

Tags: javascript

Функции по умолчанию не срабатывают

```js
var int = 1.4e-7;

console.log( int.toString() );
console.log( String(int) );
```

Comment: Что значит «не работают»?

Comment: Имя переменной int, кстати, дурацкое и вводящее в заблуждение. Это ни разу не целое число

Comment: @Alexey Ten, мне нужно получить строку "0.00000014",  `int` это пример

Comment: toFixed(8), но число надо подбирать правильно

Comment: Посмотрите здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18719775/parsing-and-converting-exponential-values-to-decimal-in-javascript